# Пагинация на сайте

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

задание сделать библиотеку(реальная с книгами и газетами) с использованием трехслойной архитектурой, где UI - asp net mvc. Первым заданием делал бизнем логику и дал(ado.net). Там я сделал методы для поиска, получения всех, сортировки по полю без пагинации. Потом дали тз на mvc. и там добавили пагинацию. И все методы что я делал без пагинации мне надо переделать так чтобы они могли принимать номер страницы и возвращать определенное количество объектов. Я стажер, и только обучаюсь к проду. Я понимаю, что это можно просто переделать, ко всем методам добавить по параметру(в логике, потом в DAL, потом в хранимые процедуры в БД). Это пока маленькая система, но ведь когда я буду на проде там будет системы большие. Ведь там я не буду переписывать все методы. В связи с этим вопрос. Как можно переделать так, чтобы не переписывать все методы   , а просто как-нибудь расширить функционал методов. И я не прошу с кодом помочь, мне бы идею подкинуть, чтоб неполучилось *овно-кода Надеюсь не запутал. Заранее спасибо

Comment: [Методы расширения](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)

Comment: Методы расширения всмысле LINQ?

Comment: вы статью прочли?

Comment: Вообще не вижу связи с этой ситуацией и методами расшерения. Лучше переписать логику, имхо. В больших проетах есть архитектура, которая должна предусматривать пагинацию или лёгкость расширения функциональности.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если правильно делать логику соблюдая все паттерны и трёхуровневую архитектуру, то переделывать если и надо будет то только метод в сервисе. И лучше списки в слое бизнес-логике писать с расчётом на пагинацию: опцинальные параметры `take` и `skip`. Например, метод для получения списка пользователей:

```
public async Task<List<UserResponse>> GetAllUsersAsync(int? skip = null, int? take = null)
{
    if (take == null)
    {
        List<User> users = await _context.Users.OrderBy(x => x.FullNameNormalized)
            .Skip(skip.GetValueOrDefault())
            .ToListAsync();
        return users.ToUserResponseList();
    }
    else
    {
        List<User> users = await _context.Users.OrderBy(x => x.FullNameNormalized)
            .Skip(skip.GetValueOrDefault())
            .Take(take.Value)
            .ToListAsync();
        return users.ToUserResponseList();
    }
}
```

Я могу вызвать этот метод с `null` параметрами и получить весь список, а могу указать смещение и сколько записей брать. Если понадобится сделать пагинацию, то мне не придётся ничего менять ни в слое доступа к данным, ни в слое бизнес-логики.

Comment: А вот в вашем случае _context - это DbContext для EF?

Comment: @arstan В моём случае - да, в вашем - это ваш провайдер бд из уровня доступа к данным.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @arstan если вас удоволетворил мой ответ, то отметьте его как правильный.